# Simulating received SMS on real Android device

Tags: android, sms, adb, simulation

I'm developing an application for Android phones which has something to do with text messages. I found many guides to simulate a received text message on an emulator but I'm testing the software on a real device.

Is there a way to fool a real Android phone to think it has received an SMS?

I've tried with `adb shell` and using `sms send` command but I think it's only available on emulators when using telnet.

Comment: Have you considered just sending an actual SMS to the phone?

Comment: Would this work: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=act.main#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDUwMSwiYWN0Lm1haW4iXQ..

Comment: I'm with 323go, just send it a real sms.

Comment: what if is a testing phone. I have 6 testings phones none of then has a sim card :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, the motive here is to create an FAKE INCOMING SMS be it for device or for an emulator.

You might need to do a bit of reverse engineering with Messaging Content Providers to achieve that. There're messaging related content providers that you can use for adding entries to the DB, which is the general method of emulating a SMS and also used by the SMS faker apps. Please be careful not to rely on this as Android doesn't guarantee that this Content Providers would have such access forever.

Also refer to this link: 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/be-careful-with-content-providers.html

Hope this helps.